# Meteor: Flowrouter url pattern - parameter locations

Tags: meteor, flow-router

I am using FlowRouter with MeteorJS, and trying to create a URL with the following pattern:

`topicRoute.route('/:topicName/:moduleName/portal', {...});`

in this case, `topicName` and `moduleName` are route params, but I would like to have a `".../portal"` url for different `topicName` and `moduleName` occurrences in the app.

This doesn't seem to work...is it not possible to put a "static part" after params?

Thank you!

Comment: what actually happens?

Comment: quite literally - nothing happens :) The route's `action` function never gets triggered (I tested with a console.log)

Comment: What is `topicRoute`? Why not `FlowRouter.route()`?

Comment: its just a previously defined named route...not really relevant, could just as easily be FlowRouter.route()

Comment: I don't really understand this: "but I would like to have a ".../portal" url for different topicName and moduleName occurrences in the app.". What's wrong with having that?

Comment: that is the question :)  - I didn't think there was anything wrong with it either. I can get a URL  to be `/portal/:topicName/:moduleName` but I cannot get it to be `/topic/:topicName/:moduleName/portal` - FlowRouter simply doesn't recognize the second route.